# What's the difference between Int16, Int32 and Int64?

Tags: c#, integer

I am using Int32 when converting from double, but what's the difference ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Int16` -> `short` -> 16-bit Integer

`Int32` -> `int` -> 32-bit Integer

`Int64` -> `long` -> 64-bit Integer